# SharePoint 2010 equivalent to SQL Profiler?

Tags: performance, caml-query, troubleshooting

Is there a way to view the CAML that is running on a SharePoint 2010 installation?

A bit like how you can monitor SQL running on a database with MS-SQL Server - is this possible with CAML and SharePoint?

Comment: Check http://the-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2011/07/know-caml-queries-executed-by.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to a certain extend you can watch CAML being executed by SharePoint Server. Here are the high level steps:

1. Go to Central Admin -> Monitoring --> Configure Diagnostic Logging -> Expand "SharePoint Foundation" and Check Monitoring

Make sure you select "Verbose" for event log and trace log and then save your settings

You may want to do IIS reset at this point.

1. Download [ULS Viewer](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer) and run it
2. Load From ULS log in the ULS log viewer to start monitoring. Filter the log entries (Edit Menu - > Modify Filter) for condition like "Message contains CAML" so that it shows only relevant messages to you real time.

I am working on a for this at http://the-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2011/07/know-caml-queries-executed-by.html

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at IDERA's tool.

http://www.idera.com/Products/SharePoint/SharePoint-page-profiler/

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like [U2U CAML builder](http://www.u2u.be/res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx) and [Stramit CamlViewer](http://spcamlviewer.codeplex.com/) to see what CAML is generated or use it to roll your own.  I don't know of anything that monitors for that type of thing though.